# Can I make a php function that turns all the data in a database into variables that can transfer to javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I'm making a virtual worlds.  I need to add players.  Is it possable to make a php function that finds all the data in a database/player data and turns each line into a variable so I can tranfer it into javascript.  The function would look something like,

```
function data() {
Finddata_from("players");
Create var p.$number;
}
```

Comment: Not sure what `Create var` is supposed to do.  But you can emit values from data to the page.  Any introductory PHP tutorial should show you how to do that.  What you have here looks like a very odd mix of PHP and JavaScript.  They are two different languages.

Comment: If this question is solved then please consider accepting an answer (not necessarily mine).

Answer (score 0):

You may create the Javascript Code and just echo it.

```
function data() {
    $data = ['john' => 200, 'marc' => 200];

    echo '<script>', PHP_EOL;
    foreach($data as $playername=> $score) {
        printf('var %s = "%s";' . PHP_EOL, $playername, $score);
    }
    echo '</script>', PHP_EOL;
}
```

Example output:

```
<script>
var john = 100;
var marc = 200;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Writing values to JavaScript on the page is no different than writing values to HTML.  Consider the following example of writing a value to HTML:

```
<div>
    <p><?php echo "some value"; ?></p>
</div>
```

This would result in:

```
<div>
    <p>some value</p>
</div>
```

From PHP's perspective, there was only that one single PHP statement.  Everything else outside of the `<?php ?>` tags is just text sent directly to the browser without PHP's involvement.  What's in that text doesn't matter.  It can just as easily be JavaScript.  For example:

```
<script>
    var someValue = "<?php echo "some value"; ?>";
    alert(someValue);
</script>
```

Would emit:

```
<script>
    var someValue = "some value";
    alert(someValue);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a JSON (JavaScript Object Notation):

```
<?php
   $con = mysqli_connect($host, ...);
   $sth = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT ...");
   $rows = array();
   while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
       $rows[] = $r;
   }
?>
<script>
   var _obj = <?php echo json_encode($rows) ?>;
   console.log(_obj);
</script>
```